# Terminal Server monitoring/recording solutions

Tags: monitoring, windows-terminal-services

I saw an ad on ServerFault for a product called [ObserveIT](http://www.observeit-sys.com/) - it looks like a brilliant product, and we're in the process of trialling it in our staging environment.

Does anyone know of any other software the offers a similar feature set? Namely:

- Recording and journaling of terminal server sessions
- Ability to view (but not control) multiple remote sessions simultaneously
- Managing multiple servers from one console is nice, but not essential

We have a half-dozen terminal servers, from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q and A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's always your basic "spy on people" type of software. [Spector 360](http://www.spector360.com/) is a good product for doing that. I've deployed it in term server environments. Works well. Collects all screenshots and info into 1 console for viewing. Does not give the ability to control sessions, but also doesn't give the ability to view them live. You can view the recorded screenshots though.

Comment: I'll give it a whirl, thanks. Doesn't really matter if we can't view it live, just as long as we can go back through it to find out if (person x) really did delete that record in the customers table